# Is "Allah" a he or she?

Tags: allah

As I know Allah doesn't have any sex but I read and hear some Muslims when talk about Allah say : He and Him

How can I call Allah in English?

Comment: "it" would be horrible, right?

Comment: There is earth-sky difference between Arabic and English grammer. For example, many languages have a `singular` and `plural`, but `Arabic` has `singular`, plural and `super plural` also. If you give some time to study Arabic grammar a little bit, you'll get the difference.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

In Arabic, God (Allah) refers to Himself using the male pronoun "هو"; unlike English, the Arabic male pronoun does not imply gender.  English, quite frankly, does not have an appropriate pronoun that fully encompasses this.

"He" is the best we have.  So that's what we use.

For further details, see also this related post: [Refering to Allah (SWT) as “him”?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/5746)

Answer (score 6):

The Surah *Al-Ikhlas* talks about the Allah Almighty in this reference. The Arabic male pronoun does not imply gender as answered by @goldPseudo.

[image: 112:1]

> Say, "He is Allah , [who is] One,

[image: 112:2]

> Allah , the Eternal Refuge.

[image: 112:3]

> He neither begets nor is born,

[image: 112:4]

> Nor is there to Him any equivalent."

[Quran:112](http://quran.com/112)

Comment: Thanks I know it! But my question was why you are using of He in translation to English.

Answer (score 0):

I think this question is trivial and need no more debate.
In Arabic and many other languages, we use "He" to refer to neutral beings. It is the problem of English that differentiate male object from female object. Using "He" as God's pronoun is much better than using "it". Since "it" refers to inanimate object, animals, and other living things other than human.

It is more respectful to call Allah a "He" than a "She", because in our 'generalization', "He" is more powerful than "She".

It's just a matter of language perspective. I think that concludes everything.

Answer (score -4):

Allah is a He and that's how the earliest Muslims recognized him. There is a verse that says "What! For you the Males(*as in worship*) and for Him the Females(*as in partners*)."

This is a new concept of a gender-neutral God that has no basis in Quran and Sunnah.

Comment: Allah is neither he nor she in the context that He is not part nor is He of His creation.  Nor is He like anything we know or comprehend.  Nothing is like Him.  That verse you quoted is totally out of context.  The context of the Ayah you quoted is that the Mushrikeen of the Prophet's time used to hate having a female child, and it is much liked to have a male child, so what they did was say that the angels were Girls, read surat Annajim.  Please make sure you properly research for an answer, and give the citations.

Comment: Why is it forbidden to say Allah is a She?

Comment: Did Allah ever call Himself She in the Quran? did the Prophet say so, no we cannot say she then.

Comment: @مجاهد Exactly! nor did the sahaba and the scholars did.