# Why Allah said himself "He" instead of "I"?

Tags: quran, allah

First of all, I know why Allah (SWT) use "He" "We", this topic related to Gender and Royalty.

Now my question is, Why Allah (SWT) use "He" instead of "I"?

See this following verse:

> He said, "Do not be afraid, ..." | قَالَلَاتَخَافَآۖ (Q20:46)

Why "He"? He could say like this:

> I said, "Do not be afraid, ..."

I found another [question](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/67765/why-allah-said-himself-as-he-instead-of-i) like this one. A guy answered that question, but he answered why Allah refer himself "We" "He". That's why I am asking the same question again.

If you know the answer please explain this in detail. I have a explanation of mine. But, I want to what other peoples think about this.

Comment: https://islamqa.info/en/answers/209022/

Comment: The same question is here: https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/62539/first-and-third-person-used-for-allah-swt-in-quran/62605#62605